# Rendering a cube with different textures on each side in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, textures

I use a sprite sheet then I make three arrays with the texture coordinates for the sides, top and bottom of the cube. My problem is that, for whatever reason, every side of my block is drawn using the texture from the tex_bottom array.

Here is the function that loads the texture:

```
int load_gl_texture(const char *filename, unsigned char *image, unsigned width, unsigned height) {
    int status = 0;

    while(!lodepng_decode32_file(&image, &width, &height, filename)) {
        GLint texSize;
        glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &texSize);

        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

        status = 1;
        break;
    }
    if (image)
        free(image);

    return status;
```

}

Here is the code for drawing the cube:

```
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    // Front Face
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_sides[0]); glVertex3fv(vertices[1]);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_sides[1]); glVertex3fv(vertices[0]);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_sides[2]); glVertex3fv(vertices[4]);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_sides[3]); glVertex3fv(vertices[5]);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad

    // Back Face
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_sides[1]); glVertex3fv(vertices[2]);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_sides[2]); glVertex3fv(vertices[6]);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_sides[3]); glVertex3fv( vertices[7]);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_sides[0]); glVertex3fv( vertices[3]);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad

    // Top Face
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_top[3]); glVertex3fv(vertices[7]);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_top[0]); glVertex3fv(vertices[5]);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_top[1]); glVertex3fv( vertices[4]);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_top[2]); glVertex3fv( vertices[6]);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad

    // Bottom Face
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_bottom[2]); glVertex3fv(vertices[0]);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_bottom[3]); glVertex3fv( vertices[2]);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_bottom[0]); glVertex3fv( vertices[3]);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_bottom[1]); glVertex3fv(vertices[1]);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad

    // Right face
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_sides[1]); glVertex3fv( vertices[2]);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_sides[2]); glVertex3fv( vertices[6]);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_sides[3]); glVertex3fv( vertices[4]);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_sides[0]); glVertex3fv( vertices[0]);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad

    // Left Face
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_sides[0]); glVertex3fv(vertices[3]);  // Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_sides[1]); glVertex3fv(vertices[1]);  // Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_sides[2]); glVertex3fv(vertices[5]);  // Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2fv(tex_sides[3]); glVertex3fv(vertices[7]);  // Top Left Of The Texture and Quad

    glEnd();
```

What is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: This code block is not enough for us to help you. Give details regarding texture setup. Apart from that, this is probably because you haven't specified the texture for each side separately (unless you are planning to map a single texture)

Comment: @SelçukCihan I load one texture from a sprite sheet, then I use OpenGL's texture coordinate system to load each individual sprite. I stole the textures from Minecraft if you want a reference point. I edited above with the function that loads the texture.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. My function that converts the block id to texture coordinates was flawed in that it returned a memory address that was being used inside the function instead of returning actual values. This caused the values to be garbage collected once there wasn't a variable holding the respective memory address. To fix this, I made the following changes:

Old:

```
float* block_id_to_coordinates(int id) {
    GLfloat tex = {(id % 16)/16.0, (id / 16)/16.0};
    return tex;
}
```

New:

```
void block_id_to_coordinates(int id, GLfloat tex[]) {
    tex[0] = (id % 16)/16.0;
    tex[1] = (id / 16)/16.0;
}
```

The new function instead uses variables declared in the draw_block function so that they can be used in the entire drawing process. So something like this:

```
float type_top[2];
block_id_to_coordinates(top, type_top); // Initialize array using the "constructor" function

float type_sides[2];
block_id_to_coordinates(sides, type_sides);

float type_bottom[2];
block_id_to_coordinates(bottom, type_bottom);
```